# Apache Nifi Expression Language - toDate formatting

Tags: datetime, apache-nifi

I am trying to format a date string using the Apache Nifi expression language and the Replace Text processor(regex). Given a date string

```
date_str : "2018-12-05T11:44:39.717+01:00",
```

I wish to convert this to:

```
correct_mod_date_str: "2018-12-05 10:44:39.717",
```

(notice how the date is converted to UTC, and character 'T' replaced by a space.)

To do this, I am currently using:

```
toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", '+00:00')
```

and this works perfectly.

However, when the date string has 6 digits in *ms*, rather than 3, things break:

```
another_date_str: "2018-12-05T11:44:39.717456+01:00"
```

is converted to:

```
incorrect_mod_date_str: "2018-12-05 10:56:36.456"
```

It seems the first 3 digits in the *ms* precision interferes with the conversion.

Appreciate inputs to resolve this -  what am I missing?

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems that's a limitation in java.

according to java documentation there is no support of more then 3 milliseconds digits.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

the simplest way is to remove extra digits like this:

```groovy
attr:replaceAll('(\.\d{3})\d*','$1'):toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"):format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", '+00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with [date time encoded in ISO 8601](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6). The problem is, that the digits after the second are defined as fragment of a second, not milliseconds.
[See answer to related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74208263/13969076)