# Timestamp to long is not correct in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to convert string timestamp to long. I receive string timestamp like this;

```
2019-03-29T19:26:36.272794Z   -> it has 6 number after seconds(272794)
```

For this, I'm using this format in **UpdateRecordProcessor**;

```
${field.value:toDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'Z'", "GMT"):toNumber()}
```

But this solution does not give the correct solution. For example, result of above timestamp string is; `1553887868794`. But this is equal to: `2019-03-29T19:31:08.794Z`.

I guess, `UpdateRecord` uses `SimpleDataFormat` in the backend. But, as far as I know, SimpleDateFormat is only work with `3` number after seconds like above result.

How can I get correct result in `UpdateRecord` of Nifi?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150828/apache-nifi-expression-language-todate-formatting/54154182#54154182

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution is enough for now. Thank you again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Nifi Expression Language - toDate formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54150828/apache-nifi-expression-language-todate-formatting)