# NiFi toDate() Function altering the content

Tags: regex, apache-nifi, to-date, str-to-date

i have been trying to convert a string to date using

```
${test:toString():toDate('dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS'):format('dd-MMM-yy HH.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS')}
```

my value for test attribute is like 13-MAR-20 15.50.41.396000000

when i'm using the above mentioned expression to convert the string to Date, it actually is changing the date as below:

test (input value):

13-MAR-20 15.50.41.396000000

time (output value)

18-Mar-20 05.50.41.000000000

please advise!

Comment: Can you test this segment by segment, and convert it to a different format e.g. `${date:toDate('dd-MMM-yy'):format('yyyy/MM/dd')}`

Comment: java date does not support `SSSSSSSSS`. you could use only 3 digits for milliseconds `SSS`

Comment: i've tried it with 3 digits it is working good. is there a way i can get 9 digit  precision on millis (in nifi)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with date time [encoded in ISO 8601](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.6).

The problem is, that the digits after the second are defined as fragment of a second, not milliseconds. If it has 3 digits, it equivalent to milliseconds. If more than 3, the `toDate()` function parse the fragment of a second as milliseconds. In your case 396000000 milliseconds = 4,58333333 days.

I solved my issue with `replaceAll()` by cutting digits to first 3.

```
${test:replaceAll('(\.[0-9]{3})([0-9]+)','$1')}
```

But my value was formatted as 18-06-20T05:50:41.396000000, so maybe you have to adjust the regex.